# json.dump adds extra square brackets - Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I need to get data from a site and create a .json file from the data.

But when I create a .json file, I get extra square brackets.

**Code:**

```
person_info = []

person_info.append(
    {
        "Name": name,
        "Mail": mail,
    }
)

with open(filename, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:

json.dump(person_info, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

**What i get from it in .json file:**

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Sample Name",
        "Mail": "No results"
    }
][
    {
        "Name": "Sample Name",
        "Mail": "Mail"
    }
]
```

**What i need to get:**

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Sample Name",
        "Mail": "No results"
    },

    {
        "Name": "Sample Name",
        "Mail": "Mail"
    }
]
```

Comment: Do you have a for loop? It seems that you have the dump inside the for and then it is adding single items to the file in every iteration. The dump should be after the for loop

Answer (score 0):

You're issue seems to be related to how you write into your file.

You're accessing the `"filename"` file in `"a"` (append) mode.

Delete the file, the  open it in "w" mode instead and this should solve your problem.